# USB not showing at all in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb

I am having tones of troubles with Ubuntu recently.My USB which I use to boot many distros,is not working.I plug it in again and again but no success.When I do lsusb it shows as abcd 1234 Unknown and I do not know what to do.I tried using a Windows computer but still no success.

If someone can help me that will be awsome!

Thanks#1

Comment: Are any of the partitions on the disk either NTFS or MSDOS? If not, that explains why it didn't show anything when connected to a Windows computer. How did `lsusb` see the USB disk before today? What does `gparted` show? **Edit your question** to include the `terminal` output of `sudo lsblk` and `sudo fdisk -l` when the disk is connected. Is the disk only USB powered, or does it have a separate power brick?

Comment: Putting the lsusb output into a comment makes it very hard to read. Please delete that comment, redo the lsusb, and edit (copy/paste) that output into your original question... and also add the other requested output... if you want the help, you'll need to follow the instructions.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/896125/usb-not-showing-at-all-in-ubuntu-16-10

Here is the link

Comment: Thanks. You forgot the `sudo lsblk` and the `gparted` of /dev/sdb. FYI: that output could have just as well been edited into your original question, by hitting the "edit" underneath your original question :-) Are you able to remove the disk drive from the enclosure and connect it to a regular PC? If the partitions are unix, then Windows can't do anything with them, but at least we'll get some clue that the drive is good (you can do SMART testing) and that the enclosure might be at fault.

Comment: No.My mum's computer was formated and has no operating system although before that,Windows 8 was installed but I was still not able to format the drive

Answer (score -1):

There are many reasons why this may be occurring. Being that you said that you use it to boot many distributions it may be that your file system is incorrect, and it is causing you the issue. The other reason why it may not be working is because the USB disk is flat out worn out. Constantly reading and writing over time can lead to the end of the USB's life.

Comment: Thank you for answering!I use it for distros like once a month!I am not sure about its end of life!